# Get the names of the Masterpages for each Web Application by powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

Is there any way to spot the master pages for site-collection or site level(better)?

I thought that, powershell can help me for this aim.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at:
[SpWeb.MasterUrl Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.masterurl.aspx)

Comment: Yeap, that's it. But could you please provide the code for ps. I'm not that good to iterate through the site collections of a web app or thtough site with ps.